# conversion failed when converting date and/ or time from character string reporting services

Tags: sql-server

I am running SQL Reporting Services 2008 with Visual Studio 2008.

I can not figure out this error and I have been racking my brains for the last few days.

Hopefully someone can help. I have tried all of the other posts with similar issues but mine still persists

Code below -

```
SELECT
SharpakStockHistory.warehouse
, SharpakStockHistory.product
, SharpakStockHistory.movement_reference
, SharpakStockHistory.movement_date
, SharpakStockHistory.transaction_type
, SharpakStockHistory.movement_source
, SharpakStockHistory.comments
, SharpakStockHistory.batch_number
, SharpakStockHistory.dated
, SharpakStockHistory.movement_quantity
, SharpakStockHistory.description
, SharpakStockHistory.analysis_c
, SharpakStockHistory.machine
, CONVERT(DATETIME, SharpakStockHistory.proddate, 3) AS proddate
, SharpakMCRef.mcname
FROM SharpakStockHistory
LEFT OUTER JOIN SharpakMCRef
                   ON SharpakStockHistory.machine = SharpakMCRef.mcref
WHERE (SharpakStockHistory.comments LIKE 'EXTRUSION MATERIAL%')
AND (SharpakStockHistory.transaction_type = 'ISSU')
AND (CONVERT(DATETIME, SharpakStockHistory.proddate, 3) >= @startdate)
AND (CONVERT(DATETIME, SharpakStockHistory.proddate, 3) <= @enddate)
ORDER BY proddate DESC;
```

Comment: As you CONVERT presumably `SharpakStockHistory.proddate` is not a DATETIME, what is it and what is its format?

Comment: Can you post the error that you get and also what is the format of the data in the fields being converted like ? Also, do you have text dates from multiple regions, i.e. 31/12/2014 and also 12/31/2014 ?

Comment: Sounds like you have some data in your "proddate" column that isn't a valid Datetime.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try this:

```
WHERE ...
 AND SharpakStockHistory.proddate between @startdate and @enddate
```